# Creating bookmarks in PDF files

Tags: hyperref, bookmarks

Which package is used to create markers like the figure:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book}

\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,headsep=10pt,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[]{titlesec}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
\setlist{nolistsep}
\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{243,102,25}
\usepackage{avant}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[style=numeric,citestyle=numeric,sorting=nyt,sortcites=true,autopunct=true,babel=hyphen,hyperref=true,abbreviate=false,backref=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\defbibheading{bibempty}{}

\usepackage{titletoc}

\contentsmargin{0cm}

% Part text styling
\titlecontents{part}[0cm]
{\addvspace{20pt}\centering\large\bfseries}
{}
{}
{}

% Chapter text styling
\titlecontents{chapter}[1.25cm]
{\addvspace{12pt}\large\sffamily\bfseries}
{\color{ocre!60}\contentslabel[\Large\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}\color{ocre}}
{\color{ocre}}  
{\color{ocre!60}\normalsize\;\titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage}

% Section text styling
\titlecontents{section}[1.25cm]
{\addvspace{3pt}\sffamily\bfseries}
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}}
{}
{\hfill\color{black}\thecontentspage}
[]

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\sffamily\normalsize\bfseries\chaptername\ \thechapter.\ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\sffamily\normalsize\thesection\hspace{5pt}#1}{}}
\fancyhf{} \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\sffamily\normalsize\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\addtolength{\headheight}{2.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhead{}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{
\clearpage\ifodd\c@page\else
\hbox{}
\vspace*{\fill}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\fi}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

    \pagestyle{empty}
    \tableofcontents
    \cleardoublepage
    \pagestyle{fancy}

    \part{Parte 1}

    \chapter{Conhecendo o SolidWorks}

    \section{Introdução}
    SolidWorks é um software de CAD (\textbf{D}esign \textbf{A}uxiliado por \textbf{C}omputador,traduzido para o português), 
    desenvolvido pela SolidWorks Corporation, adquirida em 1997 pela Dassault Systèmes S.A., e que funciona em sistemas 
    operacionais da plataforma Windows©.

    O SolidWorks é um software paramétrico, ou seja, diferentemente de outros softwares CAD, existe um processo de 
    definição dos parâmetros necessários para uma especificação da geometria de um modelo geométrico. Para ser um pouco 
    mais claro, as geometrias do modelo 3D são definidas por valores de dimensões e referências geométricas.

    Enfim, para sermos mais diretos vamos para o conteúdo deste livro onde pretendo abordar os assuntos mais importantes 
    sobre os três ambientes de trabalho deste software: \textbf{peça, montagem e detalhamento}.

    \section{1}
    \lipsum[1]
    \section{2}
    \lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: → [`hyperref`](https://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) and [`bookmark`](https://ctan.org/pkg/bookmark) or (more general) [CTAN topic `hyper`](https://ctan.org/topic/hyper)

Answer (score 2):

With the help of [Schweinebacke](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/398143/creating-bookmarks-in-pdf-files#comment990432_398143) I was able to add the ideal marker:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hidelinks,backref=true,pagebackref=true,hyperindex=true,colorlinks=false,breaklinks=true,urlcolor= ocre,bookmarks=true,bookmarksopen=false,pdftitle={Title},pdfauthor={Author}}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\bookmarksetup{
open,
numbered,
addtohook={%
\ifnum\bookmarkget{level}=0 % chapter
\bookmarksetup{bold}%
\fi
\ifnum\bookmarkget{level}=-1 % part
\bookmarksetup{color=ocre,bold}%
\fi
}
}
```

**The MWE looks like this:**

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book}

\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,headsep=10pt,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[]{titlesec}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
\setlist{nolistsep}
\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{243,102,25}
\usepackage{avant}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[style=numeric,citestyle=numeric,sorting=nyt,sortcites=true,autopunct=true,babel=hyphen,hyperref=true,abbreviate=false,backref=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\defbibheading{bibempty}{}

\usepackage{titletoc}

\contentsmargin{0cm}

% Part text styling
\titlecontents{part}[0cm]
{\addvspace{20pt}\centering\large\bfseries}
{}
{}
{}

% Chapter text styling
\titlecontents{chapter}[1.25cm]
{\addvspace{12pt}\large\sffamily\bfseries}
{\color{ocre!60}\contentslabel[\Large\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}\color{ocre}}
{\color{ocre}}  
{\color{ocre!60}\normalsize\;\titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage}

% Section text styling
\titlecontents{section}[1.25cm]
{\addvspace{3pt}\sffamily\bfseries}
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}}
{}
{\hfill\color{black}\thecontentspage}
[]

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\sffamily\normalsize\bfseries\chaptername\ \thechapter.\ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\sffamily\normalsize\thesection\hspace{5pt}#1}{}}
\fancyhf{} \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\sffamily\normalsize\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\addtolength{\headheight}{2.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhead{}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{
\clearpage\ifodd\c@page\else
\hbox{}
\vspace*{\fill}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\fi}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hidelinks,backref=true,pagebackref=true,hyperindex=true,colorlinks=false,breaklinks=true,urlcolor= ocre,bookmarks=true,bookmarksopen=false,pdftitle={Title},pdfauthor={Author}}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\bookmarksetup{
open,
numbered,
addtohook={%
\ifnum\bookmarkget{level}=0 % chapter
\bookmarksetup{bold}%
\fi
\ifnum\bookmarkget{level}=-1 % part
\bookmarksetup{color=ocre,bold}%
\fi
}
}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

    \pagestyle{empty}
    \tableofcontents
    \cleardoublepage
    \pagestyle{fancy}

    \part{Parte 1}

    \chapter{Conhecendo o SolidWorks}

    \section{Introdução}
    SolidWorks é um software de CAD (\textbf{D}esign \textbf{A}uxiliado por \textbf{C}omputador,traduzido para o português), 
    desenvolvido pela SolidWorks Corporation, adquirida em 1997 pela Dassault Systèmes S.A., e que funciona em sistemas 
    operacionais da plataforma Windows©.

    O SolidWorks é um software paramétrico, ou seja, diferentemente de outros softwares CAD, existe um processo de 
    definição dos parâmetros necessários para uma especificação da geometria de um modelo geométrico. Para ser um pouco 
    mais claro, as geometrias do modelo 3D são definidas por valores de dimensões e referências geométricas.

    Enfim, para sermos mais diretos vamos para o conteúdo deste livro onde pretendo abordar os assuntos mais importantes 
    sobre os três ambientes de trabalho deste software: \textbf{peça, montagem e detalhamento}.

    \section{1}
    \lipsum[1]
    \section{2}
    \lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]